# Importing minified javascript which requests an insecure script

Tags: javascript

I am working on an https website built in asp.net which contains a page which runs javascript using a reference to an external Javascript library.

```
<script src="https://externalwebsite.com/codey-min.js"  type="text/javascript" />
```

I have no guarantee that codey-min.js will continue to be hosted on externalwebsite.com so I have taken the code in `codey-min.js` and hosted it locally, I've swapped the above for

```
<script src="../Scripts/codey-min.js"  type="text/javascript" />
```

It turns out that codey-min.js has a reference to an http resource so now I get a a Mixed Content error, (The page xxxx was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script).

The resource requested in codey-min is only available over http.

Even if I could discover and import all the resources requested by codey-min.js I don't think I could then manually change it so it contains local references - I don't think I can successfully edit a minified file like that.

How can I bring in and reference all the js I need locally?

Comment: Have you tried faking your local environment to support https?

Comment: What actually is the external website? If it is some open source facility you can probably get all resources from somewhere like github. If it is closed source you are on shaky ground here.

Comment: @James the external website is closed source, I have no access to the original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Chromes developer tools I've discovered that the 'codey-min.js' makes local calls for resources it needs which is causing the problems.

As well as seeing all the imported js files you can 'pretty print' minified javascript in Chrome (F12 > Sources > Page > Click the `{}` in the window showing the code). That enabled me to find the requests for internal resources and also import a vaguely readable version of 'codey-min.js' into my code base. I've now found and imported the other resources into my project and edited codey-min.js so it doesn't do the local imports.